# crashing while constructing a BST from a linked-list

Tags: c, linked-list, binary-search-tree

First I read all the words and their location from a directory which contains text files and put them in a linked-list.In order to do so, I first read each text file line by line and then read the words in each line and store them in the linked-list (till here the program works perfectly).
 then I want to construct a BST which contains all the words in the linked-list.

Here is the code:

```
        typedef struct node {
             char word[100];
             char FileName[100];
             struct node* next;
        } node;  

        typedef struct BSTnode {
            char word[100];
            struct BSTnode* right;
            struct BSTnode* left;
            node* head2;
        }BSTnode;

        BSTnode* root=NULL;
        node* head=NULL;

void readAllFiles(char *path)
{
    struct stat status;
    struct dirent *object;
    DIR *dir;

    if ( (dir = opendir(path)) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Sorry, unable to open %s directory", path);
        return;
    }

    chdir(path);

    while ( (object = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        stat(object->d_name, &status);
        if (S_ISDIR(status.st_mode))
        {
            if (strcmp("..", object->d_name) == 0 || strcmp(".", object->d_name) == 0) continue;
            readAllFiles(object->d_name);
            chdir("..");
        }

        else
        {
            linebyline(object->d_name);
        }
    }
}

void linebyline (char* file1){
    int i=0,j;
    char sample [1000][1000];
    FILE* ptr;
    ptr=fopen(file1,"r");
    while (!feof (ptr)) {
        fgets(sample[i],1000,ptr);
        i++;
    }
    for (j=0;j<i;j++) {
        word(sample[j],file1);
    }
}

void word (char s1[],char* file1) {
    char a[100];
    int i,j=0,k=0,length;
    length=strlen (s1);
    for (i=0;i<length+1;i++) {
        if (!((s1[i]>='a' && s1[i]<='z') || (s1[i]>='A' && s1[i]<='Z'))) {
        a[j]='\0';
        if (a[0]>='A') {
    insert(a,file1);
  //  printf("%s\n",a);
    }
        j=0;
    }
    else {
        a[j]=s1[i];
        j++; }


    }
}

void insert (char string [],char* file1) {
    node* a=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    node* temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    strcpy(a->word,string);
    strcpy(a->FileName,file1);
    if (head==NULL) {
        head=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        strcpy(head->word,a->word);
        strcpy(head->FileName,a->FileName);
        head->next=NULL;
    }
    temp=head;
    while (temp->next!=NULL) {
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    temp->next=a;
    a->next=NULL;
}

        BSTnode* BSTinsert(BSTnode* root, node* data)
        { 

          if(root == NULL) {
            BSTnode* new_node =(BSTnode*)malloc(sizeof(BSTnode));
            strcpy(new_node->word,data->word);
            new_node->left = NULL;
            new_node->right = NULL;
              return new_node; }

            else if (strcmp (data->word,root->word)>0) {
            root->right = BSTinsert(root->right, data); }

            else {
            root->left = BSTinsert(root->left, data);
          }

          return root;

     }

    void TransferToBST (BSTnode* root,node* head) {

        while (head->next!=NULL) {
                root=BSTinsert(root,head);
                head=head->next;
        }
    }

    int main () {
        readAllFiles("m");
        TransferToBST(root,head);
        while (root->right!=NULL){
           printf("%s\n",root->word);
           root=root->right;}
```

When I run this code on CodeBlocks, it crashes and I don't know why. I appreciate your help and comments.

Comment: Please post the code in which you are creating linked-list!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon, but even more importantly,
please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).
What you've provided is minimal, but it isn't complete.  You've also not provided any sample data.  You can hard-wire your list, and you could drop the file name field since you're not storing that in the BST.  Have you checked that you can safely print your list?  Does the code calling `BSTinsert()` use the same logic to traverse the list and add items to the tree?

Comment: i posted the complete code and explained more about my code.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot dereference `NULL` pointer:

```
BSTnode* root=NULL;
node* head=NULL;
```

Then:

```
int main () {
    TransferToBST(root,head);
}
```

In `void TransferToBST (BSTnode* root,node* head) {`

look at:

```
   while (head->next!=NULL) {
```

`Head` is `NULL` Access to `head->next` will cause the crash.

Comment: The linked-list is already filled with some 1000 words, I just wanted to show that head was globally defined.

Comment: @Mahdi The program as such will not run. It is better to see the bigger picture to determine the problem. Also, make sure that a pointer is not a  `NULL` before dereferencing it.

Comment: I put the complete code and explained a little more.